# Leaflet R legend not showing for larger data sets

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
head(mydf)
  id      lat       lon type
1  1 40.43859 -79.96828    2
2  2 40.58657 -79.76769    1
3  3 40.53450 -79.21241    2
4  4 40.41032 -79.86355    2
5  5 40.44095 -80.06801    2
6  6 40.35060 -79.85733    2
```

I am using leaflet to plot like this, which works fine EXCEPT the legend showing up:

```
library(leaflet)
factpal <- colorFactor(c('#FF7F0E', '#1F77B4', '#2CA02C', '#E41A1C'), mydf$type)
mydf %>%  leaflet() %>%
    setView(-95, 35, 4) %>% addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                     options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
    addCircles(radius = 10, color = ~factpal(type)) %>%
    addLegend(position = 'bottomright', pal = factpal, values = ~type, opacity = 1)
```

However, the legend does not show up with my data set of 30K+ rows. Strangely, when I sample a smaller data frame my overall data set, the legend shows perfectly. What is wrong with my code or addLegend?

This works:

```
mydfSub <- mydf[sample(1:nrow(mydf), 1000), ]
mydfSub %>%  leaflet() %>%
    setView(-95, 35, 4) %>% addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                     options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
    addCircles(radius = 10, color = ~factpal(type)) %>%
    addLegend(position = 'bottomright', pal = factpal, values = ~type, opacity = 1)
```

Comment: Any `NA`s in the data?

Comment: No. None. That was my first thought too. Strange that it works on smaller data set.

Comment: Do you the row number that causes the issue? Is it something about that specific row, or is there some other limitation to leaflet?